# regex replace Match to replace ampersand

Tags: regex, replace

I am trying to replace a substring within a url and what I thought would be simple does not seem to be working. The string url is not always the same but will have the start of the substring I wish to replace and always end with the same character.

An example of the string:

```
http://www.xxxxx.com/limit=200&since=1443358621&results=true&token=1046xxxxxxx&until=1443418200
```

I want to replace the '&since=1443358621&' with just an '&'. The unix timestamp is different in different urls. I tried the following:

```
\&since=[^"]+&
```

but this takes everything off until like the third or fourth '&'. How can I make sure it reaches the first '&' only?

Comment: I don't know what environment you're performing this replacement in, but this should match: `&since=[[:digit:]]+&`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex for search:

```
&since=[^&]+
```

or

```
&since=\d+
```

and replace it by an empty string.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yX8iD0/1)